# Setting ComboBox SelectedIndex to 0 after adding items throws exception

Tags: c#, combobox

It's one of those days when even the simplest things don't work. TGIF. Consider the following code to populate a `combobox` which has been placed on a form using the designer:

```
   cboDisposition.Items.Add("Choose");  
   cboDisposition.Items.Add("Use as Is");  
   cboDisposition.Items.Add("Rework");  
   cboDisposition.Items.Add("Scrap");  
   cboDisposition.Items.Add("Return to Vendor");  
   cboDisposition.Items.Add("Void");  
   cboDisposition.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

   cboDisposition.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Setting the `SelectedIndex` causes an exception: `ex = {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}`

and the `SelectedIndex` is set to `-1`. Setting the value to any other `integer` between `1` and `5` works fine. Why is this happening?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code looks OK. I suspect that you have an event handler for SelectedIndexChanged, and that something in there is throwing the exception. The Microsoft docs say that 0 is a valid index to specify. In the case that there aren't any elements in the combobox, you should have received a ArgumentOutOfRangeException instead.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, use the CreateControl method to refresh the list of options in the combo box.

```
cboDisposition.CreateControl();

cboDisposition.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Then it won't throw an error.

Comment: This method is not available in my UWP app.